# AssertionError: error message must contain revert

Tags: solidity, dapps, truffle-migration, truffle-test

I have tried a lot of research. I still somehow can't find and understand why this error occurs when im in private network. But if in 127.0.0.1:7545 which ganache, everything seems to be working, all passed.

Reference: https://github.com/dappuniversity/token_sale/blob/master/contracts/DappToken.sol

Whenever I run `truffle test --network kennetwork`

[image]

I have this error 
[image]

this is my code DappToken.sol:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because ganache has implemented a workaround to forward the reason of a failed `require` but other clients will fail with a regular exception.

This is good for ganache because truffle is able to show the exact cause of an `require` failure. But the feature is not portable because other clients didn't implement a similar feature.

Comment: how to implement the ganache feature to other clients like geth local/private network?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know enough of geth to say what is needed. Likely you will need to define an EIP to add more information to public apis.

Comment: I did some research Ismael. You were right. The feature you are talking about is the `sync` and `async`. Ganache is `async` and geth is not thats why. So thanks!